# TabNavigator doesn't work for iOS in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

I can't get TabNavigator to work on iOS, although it works perfectly in Android.  Here are my steps to reproduce the problem

Open terminal window.

`react-native init tabnav`

`cd tabnav`

`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm -rf package.json`

`rm -rf package-lock.json`

Then I opened up `package.json` and pasted in the following contents:

```
{
  "name": "tabnav",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "0.49.3",
    "react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Then I opened up `App.js` and pasted in the contents:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
type Props = {};
class Page extends Component<Props> { 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Navigator = TabNavigator({
  Recent: {screen: Page},
  Popular:{screen:Page}
  }
);

export default Navigator;
```

Then I opened up the Xcode project, cleaned, and ran the project.

Then I get this error:

> undefined is not a function (near
>   '...(0,_reactNavigation.TabNavigator)...')

Why won't tab navigator work?

---

Note: if I replace all instances of tab navigator with stack navigator, the error goes away.  But I need a tab navigator, not a stack navigator

Comment: How you added react-navigation in your project ?

Comment: @ParasWatts I added the line `"react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git",` to my package.json under the dependencies section.  Then I typed `npm install`.

Comment: install it directly using npm install react-navigation --save

Comment: @ParasWatts I just tried `rm -rf node_modules; npm install react-navigation --save; npm install;`.  Then I cleaned and re-built the project.  Still the same problem.

Comment: I am using TabNavigator in two of my projects in IOS and both are working just fine.

Comment: I also used it successfully in another iOS project as well. But it's not working in this project.  What's wrong with my code/project? Any ideas?

Comment: from the code snippet, you provided it just looks fine, but without running it on my end, cannot find what the actual problem is.

Comment: Can you post your `.babelrc` and `package.json` files? There is some problem with your `environment`

Comment: @PritishVaidya ok I've updated my question to include both the files you mentioned

Comment: Hmm, seems like some other issue, maybe try checking and deleting the `.babelrc` above the `directory` in the `root folder` if present. I had checked the link [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1631)

Comment: @PritishVaidya ok thanks.  Actually what I'm going to try to do is start a completely new project, then copy my react components, package.json and media files over.  Then try to install the whole project again from the beginning.  Maybe my `ios` folder is corrupted or something, and it is missing some libraries.

Comment: @PritishVaidya  I've simplified my question and posted steps to reproduce my issue.  Should be say to follow.

Comment: @ParasWatts I've simplified my question and posted steps to reproduce the

Comment: can you please try to remove react-navigation package from package.json then install react-navigation

Comment: "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
my package.json is like this

Comment: @ParasWatts your suggestion worked.  So the problem was that my package.json had the wrong version for react-navigation.  Deleting react-navigation from package.json file, and deleting my node_modules directory, and running `npm install react-navigation --save` and `npm install` got everything working.

Comment: @ParasWatts Feel free to write your solution as answer, and I will check mark it.

Comment: I have added my answer. :) Glad it helped .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove react-navigation package from package.json then install react-navigation. Hope it helps.

---

after doing this, you will notice that package.json will list a specific version of react-natigation as opposed to just a link to a repository

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation above v2, a new TabNavigator is introducer, You can use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` to create TabNavigator in top of your screens.

```
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from "react-navigation";

const TabsAB = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
Tab_A: {
    screen: ScreenA,
....
```